# How .net allows nested transactions with TransactionScopeOption

Tags: c#, transactionscope, system.transactions

I have learned that Oracle & sql server database does not allow nested transactions. Then how does c# allow us to perform nested transactions using transactionscopeoption?

Comment: MS SQL Allows Nested Transactions, even distributed ones. Can you share your source?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server does support nested transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx).

Had it not supported nested transactions, you would (presumably) have gotten an exception when using SQL Server in a nested transaction.